# Como Resolver "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"?

Tags: c#, exceção

```
    namespace RepositorioLivrosICC
{

    public class RepositorioLivros
    {
        public static RepositorioLivros instance = null;
        private List<Livro> repositorioLivros;
        private int indice;

        public static RepositorioLivros getInstance()
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new RepositorioLivros();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        private RepositorioLivros()
        {
            this.repositorioLivros = new List<Livro>();
            this.indice = 1;
        }

        public void inserirLivro(Livro l)
        {
            l.setCodigo(indice);
            indice++;
            this.repositorioLivros.Add(l);
        }

        public bool remover(Livro l)
        {
            bool removeu = false;
            foreach (Livro aux in this.repositorioLivros)
            {
                if (aux.getCodigo() == l.getCodigo())
                {
                    this.repositorioLivros.Remove(l);
                    removeu = true;
                }
            }
            return removeu;
        }

        public bool procurar(int index)
        {
            bool achou = false;
            foreach (Livro aux in this.repositorioLivros)
            {
                if (aux.getCodigo() == index)
                {
                    achou = true;
                }
            }
            return achou;
        }

        public string listar()
        {
            string retorno = "";
            foreach (Livro l in this.repositorioLivros)
            {
                retorno += l.ToString();
            }
            return retorno;
        }
    }

    public class Livro : Object
    {

        private string nome;
        private int codigo;
        private Autor autor;

        public Livro(string nome, Autor autor)
        {
            this.setAutor(autor);
            this.setAutor(autor);
        }

        public int getCodigo()
        {
            return this.codigo;
        }

        public void setCodigo(int codigo)
        {
            if (codigo > 0)
            {
                this.codigo = codigo;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Codigo inválido");
            }
        }

        public void setNome(string nome)
        {
            if (nome != null)
            {
                this.nome = nome;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nome do livro inválido");
            }
        }

        public void setAutor(Autor autor)
        {
            if (autor != null)
            {
                this.autor = autor;
            }
        }

        public string getNome()
        {
            return this.nome;
        }

        public Autor getAutor()
        {
            return this.autor;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string retorno = "";
            retorno += "\nCodigo Livro: " + this.codigo + "\nNome Livro:" + this.nome + this.autor.ToString();
            return retorno;
        }
    }
    public class Autor : Object
    {
        private string nome;
        private string cpf;

        public Autor(string nome, string cpf)
        {
            this.setCpf(cpf);
            this.setNome(nome);
        }

        private void setNome(string nome)
        {
            if (nome != null)
            {
                this.nome = nome;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nome autor inválido");
            }
        }

        public void setCpf(string cpf)
        {
            if (cpf != null)
            {
                this.cpf = cpf;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cpf inválido");
            }
        }

        public string getNome()
        {
            return this.nome;
        }

        public string getCpf()
        {
            return this.cpf;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string retorno = "";
            retorno += "\nNome Autor: " + this.nome + "\nCpf: " + this.cpf;
            return retorno;
        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int opcao = -1;

            try
            {
                RepositorioLivros repositorio = new RepositorioLivros();


                Autor aziz = new Autor("Andre Aziz", "12738172398");
                Autor autor1 = new Autor("Carlos Julian", "1273861237");
                Livro livro1 = new Livro("Arquitetura de computadores", aziz);
                Livro livro2 = new Livro("Metodologia Cientifica", autor1);
                repositorio.inserirLivro(livro1);
                repositorio.inserirLivro(livro2);
                string aux;
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("========== Menu ==========");
                    Console.WriteLine("1 - Inserir Livro ");
                    Console.WriteLine("2 - Remover Livro ");
                    Console.WriteLine("3 - Listar Livros");
                    Console.WriteLine("0 - Sair");
                    Console.WriteLine("==========================");
                    Console.WriteLine("Digite uma opcao: ");
                    aux = Console.ReadLine();
                    opcao = Convert.ToInt32(aux);

                    switch (opcao)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            string nome, cpf, nomeLivro;
                            Console.WriteLine("Digite as informações do autor: ");
                            Console.WriteLine("Nome Autor: ");
                            nome = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("CPF: ");
                            cpf = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("Digite as informações do Livro: ");
                            Console.WriteLine("Nome Livro: ");
                            nomeLivro = Console.ReadLine();
                            Autor temp = new Autor(nome, cpf);
                            Livro temp1 = new Livro(nomeLivro, temp);
                            repositorio.inserirLivro(temp1);
                            break;
                        case 2:

                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Console.WriteLine("==== Listar ====");
                            repositorio.listar();
                            break;
                        case 0:

                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Opção Invalida");
                            break;

                    }
                } while (opcao != 0);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }



        }
    }
}
```

Ja tentei de tudo e não acho o erro.

Comment: @jbueno Para tornar a classe um [singleton](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html).

Comment: Thiago, nao basta despejar o código numa pergunta e esperar que chovam respostas. Tens que dizer, *no mínimo*, onde é que a excepcao está a ser lancada.

Comment: @dcastro O problema é que ele não está lançando nenhuma exceção, ele está rodando perfeitamente, porém fica mostrando um alerta com essa mensagem, tudo está funcionando ...

Answer (score 1):

Fiz pequenas alterações seu erro estava na linha

```
 RepositorioLivros repositorio = new RepositorioLivros();
```

e o certo nesta estrutura que você esta utilizando é

```
 RepositorioLivros repositorio = RepositorioLivros.getInstance();
```

Outra dica é, C# toda classe herda object, então não é preciso explicitar esta herança no final sempre será herdado object.

Get e sets no c# são utilizados de maneira diferente ao JAVA e é discutível o porque destas diferenças mas a comunidade costuma utilizar por padrão

```
public string Nome { get; set; }
```

Você pode fazer os cursos da [MVA](https://mva.microsoft.com/?lang=pt-br?lang=pt-BR) que são muito bons e ainda ganha certificado.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleTest
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int opcao = -1;

            try
            {
                RepositorioLivros repositorio = RepositorioLivros.getInstance();


                Autor aziz = new Autor("Andre Aziz", "12738172398");
                Autor autor1 = new Autor("Carlos Julian", "1273861237");
                Livro livro1 = new Livro("Arquitetura de computadores", aziz);
                Livro livro2 = new Livro("Metodologia Cientifica", autor1);
                repositorio.inserirLivro(livro1);
                repositorio.inserirLivro(livro2);
                string aux;
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("========== Menu ==========");
                    Console.WriteLine("1 - Inserir Livro ");
                    Console.WriteLine("2 - Remover Livro ");
                    Console.WriteLine("3 - Listar Livros");
                    Console.WriteLine("0 - Sair");
                    Console.WriteLine("==========================");
                    Console.WriteLine("Digite uma opcao: ");
                    aux = Console.ReadLine();
                    opcao = Convert.ToInt32(aux);

                    switch (opcao)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            string nome, cpf, nomeLivro;
                            Console.WriteLine("Digite as informações do autor: ");
                            Console.WriteLine("Nome Autor: ");
                            nome = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("CPF: ");
                            cpf = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("Digite as informações do Livro: ");
                            Console.WriteLine("Nome Livro: ");
                            nomeLivro = Console.ReadLine();
                            Autor temp = new Autor(nome, cpf);
                            Livro temp1 = new Livro(nomeLivro, temp);
                            repositorio.inserirLivro(temp1);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Console.WriteLine("Digite o index que quer remover:");
                            var indx = -1;
                            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out indx);
                            var tem = repositorio.procurar(indx);
                            if(tem != null)
                            repositorio.remover(tem);                                                     
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Console.WriteLine("==== Listar ====");
                            Console.WriteLine(repositorio.listar());
                            break;
                        case 0:

                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Opção Invalida");
                            break;

                    }
                } while (opcao != 0);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }



        }

    public class RepositorioLivros
    {
        public static RepositorioLivros instance = null;
        private List<Livro> repositorioLivros;
        private int indice;

        public static RepositorioLivros getInstance()
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new RepositorioLivros();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        private RepositorioLivros()
        {
            this.repositorioLivros = new List<Livro>();
            this.indice = 1;
        }

        public void inserirLivro(Livro l)
        {
            l.setCodigo(indice);
            indice++;
            this.repositorioLivros.Add(l);
        }

        public bool remover(Livro l)
        {
            return repositorioLivros.Remove(l);
        }

        public Livro procurar(int index)
        {            
            foreach (Livro aux in this.repositorioLivros)
            {
                if (aux.getCodigo() == index)
                {
                    return aux;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public string listar()
        {
            string retorno = "";
            foreach (Livro l in this.repositorioLivros)
            {
                retorno += l.ToString()+ "\n";
            }
            return retorno;
        }
    }

    public class Livro : Object
    {

        private string nome;
        private int codigo;
        private Autor autor;

        public Livro(string nome, Autor autor)
        {
            this.setAutor(autor);
            this.setAutor(autor);
        }

        public int getCodigo()
        {
            return this.codigo;
        }

        public void setCodigo(int codigo)
        {
            if (codigo > 0)
            {
                this.codigo = codigo;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Codigo inválido");
            }
        }

        public void setNome(string nome)
        {
            if (nome != null)
            {
                this.nome = nome;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nome do livro inválido");
            }
        }

        public void setAutor(Autor autor)
        {
            if (autor != null)
            {
                this.autor = autor;
            }
        }

        public string getNome()
        {
            return this.nome;
        }

        public Autor getAutor()
        {
            return this.autor;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string retorno = "";
            retorno += "\nCodigo Livro: " + this.codigo + "\nNome Livro:" + this.nome + this.autor.ToString();
            return retorno;
        }
    }
    public class Autor : Object
    {
        private string nome;
        private string cpf;

        public Autor(string nome, string cpf)
        {
            this.setCpf(cpf);
            this.setNome(nome);
        }

        private void setNome(string nome)
        {
            if (nome != null)
            {
                this.nome = nome;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nome autor inválido");
            }
        }

        public void setCpf(string cpf)
        {
            if (cpf != null)
            {
                this.cpf = cpf;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cpf inválido");
            }
        }

        public string getNome()
        {
            return this.nome;
        }

        public string getCpf()
        {
            return this.cpf;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string retorno = "";
            retorno += "\nNome Autor: " + this.nome + "\nCpf: " + this.cpf;
            return retorno;
        }

    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendi a necessidade de um Repositorio, e esta bem parecido com estruturas get e set utilizadas em JAVA. O Repositório não é para isso, e sim uma abstração da camada DAO, que porinquanto esta sendo simplesmente uma lista.

Criei essa classe:

```
public static class DAO
{
    public static List<Livro> ListaLivros = new List<Livro>();
}
```

Em seguida alterei todo seu projeto:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int opcao = -1;

        try
        {
            RepositorioLivros repositorio = new RepositorioLivros();


            Autor aziz = new Autor("Andre Aziz", "12738172398");
            Autor autor1 = new Autor("Carlos Julian", "1273861237");
            Livro livro1 = new Livro("Arquitetura de computadores", aziz);
            Livro livro2 = new Livro("Metodologia Cientifica", autor1);
            repositorio.inserirLivro(livro1);
            repositorio.inserirLivro(livro2);
            string aux;
            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("========== Menu ==========");
                Console.WriteLine("1 - Inserir Livro ");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - Remover Livro ");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - Listar Livros");
                Console.WriteLine("0 - Sair");
                Console.WriteLine("==========================");
                Console.WriteLine("Digite uma opcao: ");
                aux = Console.ReadLine();
                opcao = Convert.ToInt32(aux);

                switch (opcao)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Clear();
                        string nome, cpf, nomeLivro;
                        Console.WriteLine("Digite as informações do autor: ");
                        Console.WriteLine("Nome Autor: ");
                        nome = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("CPF: ");
                        cpf = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Digite as informações do Livro: ");
                        Console.WriteLine("Nome Livro: ");
                        nomeLivro = Console.ReadLine();
                        Autor temp = new Autor(nome, cpf);
                        Livro temp1 = new Livro(nomeLivro, temp);
                        repositorio.inserirLivro(temp1);

                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Inserido com sucesso");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Digite o codigo para remover: ");
                        int codigo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        bool retornoRemocao = repositorio.removerLivro(codigo);
                        Console.Clear();
                        if (retornoRemocao == true)
                            Console.WriteLine("Removido com sucesso.");
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("Não Encontrado.");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("==== Listar ====");
                        string retorno = repositorio.listar();
                        Console.WriteLine(retorno);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;
                    case 0:

                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Opção Invalida");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;

                }
            } while (opcao != 0);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Classe RepositorioLivro:

```
public class RepositorioLivros
{
    private List<Livro> ListaLivros { get { return DAO.ListaLivros; } }

    public RepositorioLivros()
    {
    }

    public void inserirLivro(Livro livro)
    {
        //acha o ultimo codigo da lista.
        var ultimo = this.ListaLivros.Last();
        int codigo = 1;
        if(ultimo != null)
        {
            codigo = ultimo.getCodigo() + 1;
        }

        livro.setCodigo(codigo);
        this.ListaLivros.Add(livro);
    }

    public bool removerLivro(int codigo)
    {
        //remove todos os elementos que o codigo forem = codigo. retorna o numero de elementos que removeu atraves do RemoveAll.
        int quantasRemoveu = this.ListaLivros.RemoveAll(x => x.getCodigo() == codigo);
        if (quantasRemoveu != 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;            
    }

    public bool procurarLivro(int codigo)
    {
        //procura o elemento que codigo = codigo, se nao achar, ele retorna nulo.
        Livro achou = this.ListaLivros.Find(x => x.getCodigo() == codigo);
        if (achou != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public string listar()
    {
        string retorno = "";
        foreach (Livro l in this.ListaLivros)
        {
            retorno += l.ToString();
            retorno += "\n";
        }
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

Classe Livro:

```
public class Livro : Object
{

    private string nome;
    private int codigo;
    private Autor autor;

    public Livro(string nome, Autor autor)
    {
        this.setNome(nome);
        this.setAutor(autor);
    }

    public int getCodigo()
    {
        return this.codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo)
    {
        if (codigo > 0)
        {
            this.codigo = codigo;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Codigo inválido");
        }
    }

    public void setNome(string nome)
    {
        if (nome != null)
        {
            this.nome = nome;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nome do livro inválido");
        }
    }

    private void setAutor(Autor autor)
    {
        if (autor != null)
        {
            this.autor = autor;
        }
    }

    public string getNome()
    {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public Autor getAutor()
    {
        return this.autor;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string retorno = "";
        retorno += "\nCodigo Livro: " + this.codigo + "\nNome Livro:" + this.nome + this.autor.ToString();
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

Classe Autor:

```
public class Autor : Object
{
    private string nome;
    private string cpf;

    public Autor(string nome, string cpf)
    {
        this.setCpf(cpf);
        this.setNome(nome);
    }

    private void setNome(string nome)
    {
        if (nome != null)
        {
            this.nome = nome;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nome autor inválido");
        }
    }

    public void setCpf(string cpf)
    {
        if (cpf != null)
        {
            this.cpf = cpf;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cpf inválido");
        }
    }

    public string getNome()
    {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public string getCpf()
    {
        return this.cpf;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string retorno = "";
        retorno += "\nNome Autor: " + this.nome + "\nCpf: " + this.cpf;
        return retorno;
    }

}
```

Comment: esse é meu primeiro codigo em C#, depois que eu postei eu vi que tinha algumas coisas que precisavam ser mudadas... e eu mudei

Comment: Marque como resposta correta caso tenha resolvido seu problema.

Comment: Acredito que ele esta começando agora, e não deva entrar coisas muito complexas agora como manipular listas com linq e lambda. são conceitos meio complexos de se entender.